# Apache 2 mod_rewrite problem

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^browse/videos/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /videos.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)/(.*) /playvideo.php?videoid=$1&title=$2
</IfModule>
```

url www.example.com/browse/videos/z/0/1/LastAdded  goes to videos.php

but url www.exaple.com/videos/10/play.html also goes to videos.php not to playvideo.php

Why?

Comment: It looks like Gumbo gave you the answer you needed. If so, please accept his answer by clicking the check mark next to his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews). Try to disable it with:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Furthermore, you should use more specific pattern than `.*`, for example `[^/]+`:

```
RewriteRule ^browse/videos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /videos.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4
RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /playvideo.php?videoid=$1&title=$2
```

Comment: I found        
 <Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    [...]
</Directory>

after deleting MultViews everything works ok.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that is hapenning to you but anyway you should be using something like this.

```
RewriteRule ^browse/videos/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) /videos.php?sortby=$1&filter=$2&page=$3&title=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^videos/(.+)/(.+) /playvideo.php?videoid=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. To track down why it doesn't work for you, you should enable mod_rewrite logging:

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog logs/rewrite.log
```

Then you should try to understand what's written there. And if you don't understand it, post it here and we will try to explain it.